# DataGrid column headers not displaying diacritics in VS2015/WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid, visual-studio-2015, diacritics

I have DataGrid, whose columns are autogenerated and using behavior, its column headers are set to text with diacritics (ěščřžýáíé). At runtime, everything worked fine in Visual Studio 2013, but diacritics is messed up in Visual Studio 2015. I have `Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("cs-CZ")` in constructor of each window, but that does not help. So it seems that in VS2015 there are more major fuck-ups than Object Browser, Navigation Bar and missing SQL Tools, which must be installed manually.

Anyone have solution except throwing out VS2015 and using VS2013?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in encoding of source files containg attribute with descriptions with diacritics. I solved it by copying class code, deleting class file, creating new class file and pasting original code into it. Visual Studio saved class file in its encoding. This happened after migration from VS2013 to VS2015 so maybe it is bug.